# Python Opencv2 imshow is closing immediately even with waitKey(0)

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I'm using wsl2 and VScode as the editor. The code in question is simply:

```
image = cv2.imread('sample.png')
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The first run goes smoothly and lets me inspect the image until I press a button. However after the first run the picture shows up for a quarter of a sec and then disappears. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: this needs more debugging details. as it stands, this can't be reproduced.

Comment: I don't really know how to give more details. All the required libraries have been installed etc. :/

Comment: open a powershell or cmd terminal, or whatever's required to deal with WSL2, **if** your python and opencv were installed in the guest OS (they can run perfectly fine on windows natively, so you should **not** involve WSL2 at all). try to replicate the issue OUTSIDE of vscode. describe *precisely* what you do.

Comment: Hmm... it does seem like using powershell for running the script fixes the issue..  I was using virtualenv so basically all I had to do was activate it and install Tesseract for windows and add: `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"` to the script. After that running it from the powershell it worked. However I would still like to know what could be causing the issue as I've tried both vscode's terminal and wsl2 bash to try and run the script.. Thanks anyway, this will let me go forward for now!

Answer (score 1):

> However after the first run the picture shows up for a quarter of a sec and then disappears.

This appears to be a problem triggered by the first run. Could it be that you'll need to add [`cv2.destroyAllWindows()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga6b7fc1c1a8960438156912027b38f481) to the end of your code?

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('sample.png')
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already tried that and it didn't help.. :(

Comment: @skudev That's too bad :( Have you used the cv2.imwrite() method before?

Comment: Nah, I don't think I have.. I'm pretty new to using opencv as it stands

Comment: @skudev Well, if all fails, you can still view the images by doing `cv2.imwrite("temp.png", img)`.

Comment: Oh heck.. Yeah I've used imwrite before just didn't think I'd be using it this soon in the development cos I would usually use it to print the end results, but yeah you're right that's one way to do it! Thanks, got it working with powershell, but if that feels too clunky for me as a bash user I'll certainly use your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the problem but a workaround worked for me.

I don't press any key to close the OpenCV window. I kill the terminal using the ️ button in the VSCode terminal.

Please consider if even 1 time you press any key to close the OpenCV window, then you have to restart your WSL. So, from the beginning, just kill the terminal instead of pressing any key.

But this is just a temporary workaround. I hope other people can help to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by updating my `WSL version` here:

```
aka.ms/wslstorepage
```